# Falta traducir "need review" en página de revisiones

Tags: soporte, traducciones

[En la pestaña "estadísticas" de la página de revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats) aparece el texto "need review"; hace falta traducirlo por "necesitan revisión".